# Change function keyEvent to swipeEvent in Typescript

Tags: typescript, scroll, swipe

I wanted to change the KeyEvents() function for another that manages the movement of the swipe, that is, if I move down to do one thing and if I move upwards I do another. It would be changing the movement of keys by the swipe.

I hope someone can give me an example or something. 
I leave the function I want to change here below. Thank you very much

```
KeyEvents() {

    if (this.subskey != undefined)
      this.subskey.unsubscribe();

    this.subskey = this.APPService.keyEvent$.subscribe((event) => {

      switch (event.keyCode) {

        case this.keyCodes.KEY_UP:
          this.isText('UP');
          break;
        case this.keyCodes.KEY_DOWN:
          this.isText('DOWN');
          break;
      }
    });
  }
```